# sqlite Android - how to get value of specific col /row

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method that i pass an id to and then want to find the row in that table that matches the id, and returns a string that is the colLabel of that row:

```
public String getIconLabel(int id){
        String label;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colL" FROM " + allIcons + " WHERE " +colIconID + "="+id; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        label = //HELP

        return label;

    }
```

I am unclear as to how to set label to be that specific column of the selected row?

please help

Answer (score 8):

```
if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(cursor != null)
{
cursor.moveToFirst();
String label = cursor.getString(0);
}
```

0 parameter represents your column index. Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).